# Blender Memory Issue

Tags: rendering, memory-management

I am running Blender 3.5, and I have a scene in blender that crashes blender. I noticed that when I open the project, Blender uses all 32GB of my ram within a few seconds. Trying to render the scene in Eevee or Cycles causes an instant crash.

Computer Details:
32GB DDR4 Ram

Rtx 3060

Intel Core i7-7700k

[image: Memory Usage]

My RAM memory is full. I believe my VRAM is fine although it crashes before I am able to check.

Answer (score 0):

See if any of the possible causes listed here apply to your project:
https://support.render.st/portal/en/kb/articles/rendering-blender-projects-that-have-high-memory-requirements

Also, if you have simulations/physics in the project, try lowering the resolution for them.

If nothing else works, consider using a render farm for the job.